# How can I sum Pandas Dataframe values in multi-index pivot whether they exist or not?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pivot table that is created with the following code:

```
AdminPivot = pd.pivot_table(admindata, index=['Function Name', 'Manager'], values=['Paid Hours'])
```

[image]

```
+---------------+-----------+------------+
| Function Name |  Manager  | Paid Hours |
+---------------+-----------+------------+
| Function 1    | Manager 1 |       0.21 |
| Function 2    | Manager 2 |       0.73 |
| Function 3    | Manager 1 |      2.335 |
|               | Manager 3 |       0.51 |
|               | Manager 4 |        1.4 |
|               | Manager 5 |      0.796 |
|               | Manager 6 |       0.48 |
|               | Manager 7 |         12 |
| Function 4    | Manager2  |       0.15 |
| Function 6    | Manager 1 |       0.87 |
|               | Manager 3 |       0.31 |
+---------------+-----------+------------+
```

I would like to add up the total number of Paid hours for only a subset of managers for each function. That is to say I am interested in getting this:

```
Sum of Function 1 Total Paid Hours if managers is (Manager 5, 6, 7)
Sum of Function 2 Total Paid Hours if managers in (Manager 2, 6, 7)
Sum of Function 3 Total Paid Hours if managers in (Manager 1, 3, 6, 7)
```

I can easily Index the pivot to get the value for any particular manager:

```
AdminPivot.loc[('Function 1', 'Manager 1'), 'Paid Hours']
```

Subsequently, one could repeat those values and essentially hard code the managers with if statements. However, there has to be a more elegant approach.

Specifically, how would one iterate over these given:

- There may be no hours assigned to that function in a given pull (Null)
- There may be no hours assigned to a manager in a given pull (Null)
- The managers may change

I'm trying to find a nice way to iterate over this without recreating `loc` statements for every function and every manager and adding them - with an `if` statement for whether it exists. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I think you create a new `MultiIndex` with the desired tuple combinations: `[('Function 1', 'Manager 5'), ('Function 1', 'Manager 6'), ...]` then you `.reindex` with that and can sum across the 0th level. But hard to provide a concrete solution from an image.

Comment: Sorry about the image - there was no easy way to include a table that I'm aware of. I converted it to an Ascii table which can be converted. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get a list of all of your required combinations, which allows you you create all of the ids:

```
l = [('Function 1', ['Manager 5', 'Manager 6', 'Manager 7']),
     ('Function 2', ['Manager 2', 'Manager 6', 'Manager 7']),
     ('Function 3', ['Manager 1', 'Manager 3', 'Manager 6', 'Manager 7'])]

ids = [(x, z) for x,y in l for z in y]
```

Then you can `.reindex` + `.sum`

```
df.reindex(ids).sum(level=0)

               Paid Hours
Function Name            
Function 1          0.000
Function 2          0.730
Function 3         15.325
```

---

The output of `.reindex` will be the following, only including rows that you want, and filling with `NaN` where there was no data, which is subsequently ignored in `.sum`

```
                         Paid Hours
Function Name Manager              
Function 1    Manager 5         NaN
              Manager 6         NaN
              Manager 7         NaN
Function 2    Manager 2       0.730
              Manager 6         NaN
              Manager 7         NaN
Function 3    Manager 1       2.335
              Manager 3       0.510
              Manager 6       0.480
              Manager 7      12.000
```

Comment: That works very well and took me some time to get together properly. I went back and simplified it and just removed all rows in the original data set (prior to the pivot) that had Managers not in the requested data set. Then either doing a sum or pivot provided exactly what I needed. Thank you for the help!